# Question about remaking a song in midi

Tags: midi

I have been practicing fully remaking songs made by other artists. 
But ive faced a giant problem since then. 
I cant hear all the tracks. yes i can hear the main tracks and some other ones but when it comes to more detail i cant hear them. 
Take Avicii's sunset Jesus for example i cannot figure what the individual track is in the bridge part is. 
no matter how hard i try i searched for the songs stems, midi documents, songs breakdown, there were one or two but it didnt show me the midi.
so i was wondering there must be a better way for this. because other artists did it so can some one tell me any tips and tricks on this?

Comment: My general tips for transcribing recordings https://music.stackexchange.com/a/82401/51766

Comment: It sounds like part of the question has to do with how to transcribe when some parts are buried in the mix. That is a matter of practice and gaining experience and knowledge so that you can better recognize things that are difficult to hear, but also of judiciously filling in the gaps in your transcription with something sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really the only away to be able to do this is practise, practise, then when you're getting fairly good at it... practise some more.

At the end of the day, you can only do as well as your actual ability to recognise pitch, so you'll probably end up somewhere between these two scenarios...

I've been known to loop one single chord round & round & round & round; whilst hitting almost random notes up the keyboard, until I have found exactly what was being played. [You might be able to tell from that, I don't have the world's greatest ears, but I'm tenacious.]

I have a friend who can play a couple of bars of a full symphony & write every instrument out on paper score, down the page. He'll then play that couple of bars once more to check his work & go on to the next couple of bars.

Most of the people I know are somewhere between those two extremes. You can play them a song 2 or 3 times & they can then play back an approximation, an overview, of how it was structured. They have grasped the big picture quickly, but would then have to go back to get all the details exactly as originally played.